# xtrlock alternative for Wayland GNOME

Tags: gnome, wayland, screen-lock

As the title says, I'm looking for a program or an extension for GNOME that is similar to [xtrlock](https://man.archlinux.org/man/xtrlock.1.en) but works under a Wayland session, locking the session with a transparent background.

I'm aware of the existence of [swaylock](https://github.com/swaywm/swaylock), but it doesn't seem to work in GNOME, because it complains about the lack of some Wayland protocols.

Thanks in advance